# Can anyone explain why SINGLE_USER mode might be causing my upgrade script to fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, build-automation, bamboo

I'm working on an automated deployment and need to make sure that there are no other active connections during the database upgrade. Originally I was restarting the SQL server before running the upgrade scripts, but I understand that this is a rather heavy handed approach.

So I've used the pre-deployment script to add the following to the beginning of every upgrade:

```
ALTER DATABASE XXXXX SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

And I've used the post-deployment script to add the following to the end of every upgrade:

```
ALTER DATABASE XXXXX SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

This seems to be very hit and miss. It's run fine against one test server but has failed on another, with the following error:

> Database 'XYZ' is already open and can only have one user at a time.

This error crops up as soon as it hits the following line in the upgrade script, which appears about half way down on line 39884 (and it's the first time that it's featured in the script):

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

My understanding of SINGLE_USER mode was that it'll kill off other connections to the database whilst keeping the connection that's running the upgrade script alive - and it'll prevent any further connections until MULTI_USER mode is restored.

If this is the case, does anyone know why it would suddenly block the connection half way through running the script?

**UPDATE 1**

I've just run through the upgrade script locally with no issues, so the issue is not related to the SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON statement specifically. I think it's down to timing and connections. I still don't understand the error though, given that this script is all run as part of the same connection.

**UPDATE 2**

Well I've run the script again, and I've used the same approach with other database upgrade scripts as well, and it's not happened again. So it's just going to be one of those potential problems that may or may not come back to haunt me on another day!

**UPDATE 3**

I've not managed to glean an explanation for this behavior, and it would surface during some deployments, but not others. In the end, I've removed the SINGLE_USER switch altogether and will run upgrades without it.

Comment: Did you turned off the `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` option? From BOL: Before you set the database to SINGLE_USER, verify that the AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC option is set to OFF. When this option is set to ON, the background thread that is used to update statistics takes a connection against the database, and you will be unable to access the database in single-user mode. For more information, see ALTER DATABASE SET Options (Transact-SQL).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx

Comment: Yeah I spotted that in BOL but haven't set it specifically. If I have a look at the database options in Management Studio, the "Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously" option is set to "False" - I'm assuming that's the right one?

Comment: Yes, thats the right one.

Comment: I have no other ideas, except that while the scipt runs the utility tries to make a new connection (dont ask why), or there is a reinitialization when the SET command runs and the server treats it as a new connection attempt. Check the profiler while the script is running (or try to build a *.dacpac file (if you did not do that before) and deploy that with SqlPackage.exe utility from Bamboo).
Also check the options of the test and the production server, there could be the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm now setting AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC to OFF in the pre-deployment script just before setting SINGLE_USER mode, just in case it makes a difference. Going to let the daily build run overnight and see what happens!

Comment: You are welcome, have fun and happy coding :)

Comment: Leave Profiler running against a build/deploy cycle.  Collect connection-related events.  Might give you a clue as to who's trying to do what.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I'll certainly give that a go if the opportunity arises. I have a feeling this is going to be one of those things that happens only once in a while, though, and certainly never when I'm running the profiler and waiting for it to happen! :)

Comment: What if someone/something else already set the db to SINGLE_USER before your srcipt run? Will it effectively produce your error message?

Comment: @tmlai - It would, but I'm getting the error half way through running the script (roughly 40k lines in), which is what confuses me. The connection has already been made, and single_user mode put in place for the connection running the script.

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy-paster error, but doesn't the post deployment script need to set back to multi-user?

Comment: Oops - well spotted! I've updated the question.

Comment: @MattWinward - Did you figure it out? I have exactly the same problem and my "Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously" is set to False as well. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but not. But honestly, running upgrades without it has been fine so far. The only time I do use it is just before restoring test baseline databases, as it's a good way to kill off open connections, and the restored database is already MULTI_USER by default.